# 2 Timothy 4:3-4. Is Paul referring to the church in his day, or the church of today?

Tags: chronology, 2-timothy

In 2 Timothy 4:3-4 (niv), it is written:

4 In the presence of God and of Christ Jesus, who will judge the living and the dead, and in view of his appearing and his kingdom, I give you this charge: 2 Preach the word; be prepared in season and out of season; correct, rebuke and encourage—with great patience and careful instruction. **3 For the time will come when people will not put up with sound doctrine. Instead, to suit their own desires, they will gather around them a great number of teachers to say what their itching ears want to hear. 4 They will turn their ears away from the truth and turn aside to myths.**

Comment: That is easy - the verbs are all future tense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose 4 central pieces of context:

- The verb  Ἔσται ("there will be") is given in the future tense--Paul
  is anticipating something that will happen
- Paul is speaking to Timothy (giving him a charge,
  second-person-singular commands such as κήρυξον in verse 2)
- Paul expects to die soon (see verse 6)
- The errors Paul describes don't come with an end-date...he doesn't give any hint that this will be a temporary problem

This is not to say that there haven't been doctrinal issues in the past--the epistle to the Galatians is a case in point that Paul has had to deal with incorrect teachings among the faithful before.

But Paul knows that he himself won't be there to deal with the contentions that will arise, and so he is counseling Timothy to do specific things to lay a solid foundation to guard Christians against the deceptions that will come.

That Paul believed there would be great opposition & organized wickedness preceding the return of Christ is evident from his teachings to the Thessalonians (see 2 Thess 2:3-4).

Paul's statement neither rules out the possibility of false doctrine being taught in the past nor false doctrine being taught in the future; his counsel is how to deal with (and prepare for!) false doctrine. This was doubtless applicable in the first century and remains relevant today.

Comment: +1 While I don't want to discredit God's inspiration in Paul's letters, the problems he faced with Greek philosophy, such as in 1 Cor. 15, gave him a good indication that this was what Christianity would face.

Answer (score 3):

To analyse these 2 verses you also need to consider the previous context - the word “for” is used here as a conjunction, so it ties this verse to the previous sentence in 2 Timothy 4:1-2. As a conjunction, it is defined as “because; since” (American Heritage Dictionary).

Therefore, Paul was saying that preaching the Word in and out of season and using it for reproof, rebuke, and exhortation are to be done because a time is coming when people will not receive that ministry of the Word. Timothy had a window of opportunity at that present time that he needed to take advantage of.

There are periods of time in history and in every individual’s life when people are more receptive to the Word of God than at other times. For instance, times of great loss, such as the death of a loved one, often soften a person’s heart toward the Lord. National crises, such as war or natural disasters, tend to do the same thing.

We don’t wait on calamity or other occurrences to make special opportunities to preach the Word. The very context of this verse says we are to “preach the word...in season [and] out of season” (2 Timothy 4:2, brackets mine), but we do need to know which season it is and take full advantage of the special opportunities.

As explained, this could be speaking about times that occur in every individual’s life and in every generation, when one’s heart becomes insensitive to God’s Word. *However,* this may also be a prophecy that will be fulfilled in the end times.

The Greek word “KNETHO” that was translated “itching” in this verse literally means “to scratch, i.e. (by implication) to tickle” (Strong’s Concordance). Thayer’s Greek-English Lexicon says this Greek word means “desirous of hearing something pleasant.” Paul was clearly describing a time when preachers will minister for the applause of people instead of the approval of God. They will be desirous of hearing pleasant things said about them.

The Living Bible translated this as “people won’t listen to the truth but will go around looking for teachers who will tell them just what they want to hear.”

The true ministry of God’s Word will not always produce pleasant things being said. There are unpleasant times when we need to be rebuked or challenged. Preachers need to take extreme caution not to preach just what people want to hear but what the Lord wants them to say. Those involved with teaching/preaching need to be careful *not* to get to where the motivation for ministry is the recognition of man instead of the approval of God.